# How to sort an alpha numeric list in python?

Tags: python

How to sort list by alphanumeric values

```
a = ['v1_0005.jpg', 'v1_00015.jpg', 'v2_0007.jpg', 'v2_0002.jpg']
```

while sorting list using `a.sort()` I get

```
['v1_0005.jpg', 'v1_00015.jpg', 'v2_0007.jpg', 'v2_0002.jpg']
```

which means sorting order is wrong, I expect list is sort by alphanumeric value in python

Expected list to be :

```
['v2_0002.jpg','v1_0005.jpg','v2_0007.jpg', 'v1_00015.jpg']
```

Comment: Did you mean "while sorting list using `a.sort()` i get" (sort instead of list) ?

Comment: Note that `'v1_00017.jpg'` is less than `'v1_0002.jpg'`, because the first differing character is `'1'` vs. `'2'`, and `'1'` < `'2'`.  If you want to do a more advanced sort, you'll need to extract the numeric portion from the string and convert it to a number.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem: your list format is quite wrong - instead of `v1_00015.jpg` it should be `v1_0015.jpg` (no extra `0`). Without that zero Python built-ins `.sort()` and `sorted()` work correctly. To transform the list, you can use this:

```
for i,e in enumerate(a):
    while len(a[i]) > 11:
        a[i] = e.replace('v1_0', 'v1_')
```

It replaces `v1_0` to `v1_` in every `a` item till item length `== 11`. Then just use `a.sort()`:

```
a.sort()
print(a)
```

And it prints:

```
['v1_0001.jpg', 'v1_0002.jpg', 'v1_0003.jpg', 'v1_0015.jpg', 'v1_0017.jpg']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to some techniques inorder to get the result that you want, ie you have to write a sorting function with the conditions.

So here you can make use of regex and lambda in python inorder to sort as you wish

```py
import re
def sorted_nicely( l ):
    """ 
    Sorts the given iterable in the way that is expected.
 
    Required arguments:
    l -- The iterable to be sorted.
 
    """
    convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text
    alphanum_key = lambda key: [convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key)]
    return sorted(l, key = alphanum_key)
              
# Driver code
a = ["v1_0001.jpg","v1_0002.jpg","v1_0003.jpg","v1_00017.jpg","v1_00015.jpg"]
print(sorted_nicely(a))
```

Output

```
['v1_0001.jpg', 'v1_0002.jpg', 'v1_0003.jpg', 'v1_00015.jpg', 'v1_00017.jpg']
```

Comment: This method works only for same type of values in list A = ['v1_0001.jpg', 'v2_0002.jpg', 'v1_0003.jpg', 'v1_00015.jpg', 'v2_0007.jpg'] what to do for sorting

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to use the numeric values. So you need to parse them out...
This can be done with a one-liner as so -

```
a = ['v1_0001.jpg', 'v1_00015.jpg', 'v1_00017.jpg', 'v1_0002.jpg', 'v1_0003.jpg']
a.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('v1_')[1].split('.jpg')[0]))
print(a)
# ['v1_0001.jpg', 'v1_0002.jpg', 'v1_0003.jpg', 'v1_00015.jpg', 'v1_00017.jpg']
```

Comment: What? is this a new question?? If so please explain...

Comment: You're combining questions from other posts. Please post *one* clear question, with expected output and example data. You might want to read the guide on writing SO questions...